# Tkinter(python) disabled buttons calls method

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have such python script based on Tkinter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*- 
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
root = ttk.Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1280, 800))
root.title(u'СКЗ Аналитик')
def pre(event):
    print 'Something'
button3=Button(root,state =    DISABLED,text='Test',width=10,height=1,fg='black',font='arial  8')
button3.place(x = 1200, y = 365)
button3.bind('<Button-1>', pre)
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see the button is disabled but function 'pre' works whan i pushes disabled    button.The visual it disabled but...Anyone, can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `DISABLED` field of the button only controls the built-in callback for the button.  If you make a separate "handmade" binding on your own, the state of the button will not affect that.

Here's how to make the disabling functionality work as you expect:

```
button3=Button(root, command = pre, state =    DISABLED,text='Test',width=10,height=1,fg='black',font='arial  8')
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use the built-in command field for the button.
button3.place(x = 1200, y = 365)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have disabled your button but it does not unbind the the function. You need to unbind the function which is associate to the button.

You need to add `button3.unbind('<Button-1>')` this line.

You can update your code like this :

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
root = ttk.Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1280, 800))
root.title(u'СКЗ Аналитик')
def pre(event):
    print 'Something'
button3=Button(root,state =    DISABLED,text='Test',width=10,height=1,fg='black',font='arial  8')
button3.place(x = 1200, y = 365)
button3.bind('<Button-1>', pre) 
button3.unbind('<Button-1>') #updated line
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do an unbind() worked for me. thanks.